# Compound words/noun phrases in english with different number of words in plural/singular form

Tags: grammatical-number, countable-nouns

Are there any cases where the plural and singular form of an English compound word or noun phrase differ in the number of words contained?

In all cases I can think of, the actual words within the noun phrase will change based on the grammatical number, but the number of words will not.

Examples,

- `large red car` becomes `large red cars` in plural form. *Both phrases have 3 words*
- `this apple` becomes `these apples` - *2 words in each form*

Are there any cases where the number of words will be different?

*Background: I'm writing an app that performs basic natural language processing and, if my hypothesis is true, I can simplify its implementation significantly.*

Comment: If you're talking about orthographic words rather than lexemes, numbers will be an exception: one car ==> two hundred and seventy-one cars. Perhaps this is not a problem for you. Other quantifiers (a single example ==/==> *five single examples) don't behave nicely either.

Comment: In my case, I'm planning to restrict numbers to the symbols (i.e. 0-9), which I can treat as a single 'word', so I'm hoping to avoid the 'spelled-out' numbers issue. Many thanks for your reply and for highlighting the quantifier issue - that gives me something to look into. Thanks

Comment: There's the simple example: "a car" --> "cars". But it sounds like you already know about that, and can allow for it.

Comment: What about collective nouns? A sheep vs. A flock of sheep.

Comment: @Julian That's my line of thought too. We can disregard quantifiers and adjectives because they will always remain the same (I think!). What the question boils down to is - are there any single word, singular nouns which *must* be 2 or more words in the plural. A flock of sheep, unfortunately, can still be written as 'sheep' (plural).

Comment: @Mynamite that depends on the sentence - 'The road was blocked by sheep', 'The road was blocked by a sheep', 'The road was blocked by two sheep', 'The road was blocked by a flock of sheep'. So the singular here is two words, the specific plural is two words, but the non-specific plural can be one word or four words. But you can't replace 'sheep' with 'a flock of sheep' in 'Sheep are farmed all over the world'. Of course you can't meaningfully use 'A sheep is farmed all over the world'.

Comment: @Julian The permutations are endless!  :)  I guess it depends on whether these can be avoided in an app.

Comment: @Myanmite - indeed. Wheelie - do you think you have an example of singular and plural having a different number of words now? Do you want this as an answer?

Comment: This is an apple (4 words) ---> These are apples (3 words)? In this case the number of words are reduced not increased. "This is apple" is not grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be no, there aren't any such plurals. The comments section on the question have pointed out a few interesting cases but they don't apply to the specific requirements you were looking for:

> numerical counts: one car => two hundred cars
>
> article removal: a car => cars
>
> collective nouns: a sheep => a flock of sheep

One additional exception would be adjectives that become invalidated when there are two:

> a single wolf => two single wolves

But since your restriction appears to be of the form `[0-9] [noun]` I think you can escape these.

The only evidence I have to offer on my behalf is [Wikipedia's article on plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals) and their extensive irregularities section. Nothing I saw on the article had an example of what you were looking for.

If anyone happens to come across an example I am more than willing to update the answer. In the meantime, I think it is safe to say that there are no such plurals -- and if there are they are *extremely* rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native English-speaker, I'm Chinese. So My English is definately not as half good as yours. But Your question is so interesting that I would like to try to find some answer——

It took me some time to think of some words like vice-chairman, vice-champion...

As far as i know, the plural forms of these words with hyphen ought to be like "vice chairmen" and "vice champions", am I right? If so, there are some words in English with different number of words in plural/singular form.

Comment: No, sorry; it's vice-chairmen and vice-champions. A *vice champion* would be something quite different! (Because *vice* has a number of meanings.)

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. But, when and where did i I see "vice chairmen" and "vice presidents" then?

Comment: It's acceptable not to hyphenate (although it's usual to do so). The thing is that plurals don't **lose** the hyphen.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It wouldn't mean anything, though, would it? Apart from the normal usage as 'substitute', *vice* isn't an adjective. So a vice champion wouldn't really mean anything. Or does it?

Comment: @mikhailcazi Nouns can be used attributively. [Vice as a noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vice)